Golang - K8S DeepCopyInto function failing because Secret type undefined
I have the following function, with which I'm trying to copy a secret into another namespace. My GO code fails saying that the Secret type is undefined, but it should be inherited from the core/v1 import. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
package v1

import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
import corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"

// DeepCopyInto copies all properties of this object into another object of the
// same type that is provided as a pointer.
func (in *corev1.secret) DeepCopyInto(out *corev1.Secret) {
    out.Data = in.Data
    out.NamespacedName = in.NamespacedName
    out.NamespacedName.namespace= in.Labels["destination-namespace"]
    
}

Thank you.
I tried changing from Secret to corev1.Secret but still see the same error.

corev1 is a Kubernetes package with a Secret type with a DeepCopyInto method. You should not try to add types secret (lowercase "s") to this package. To copy Kubernetes resources, it would be better to use the relevant Get method to retrieve the source e.g. Secret, change its properties (e.g. namespace) and then use the relevant Create method to create the revised Secret in the destination namespace.
